# Instance of <Contact> in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, contacts

I'm using `contacts_service: ^0.6.0` package, and I want to print the phone numbers from my phone book but it is printing Instance of < Contact > instead of actual phone number.

[This is my phones screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8l50.jpg)

This is my output in debug panal.

`I/flutter ( 8457): [Instance of 'Contact', Instance of 'Contact'].`

This is my code:

`

```
_getContacts() async {
    List<Contact> _contacts =
    (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
    setState(() {
      contacts.addAll(_contacts);
      print(contacts);
    });
  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are printing the Instance itself, not the data inside them. So to print the data inside the Contact Instance you need to extract the data from it. For example:

```
_getContacts() async {
 List<Contact> _contacts =
 (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
 setState(() {
   contacts.addAll(_contacts);
   for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){
     print(contacts[i].displayName);
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much @Aloysius it worked for me, but you have some syntactical error in it so please edit them so that I can give tick mark to you. `for(var i=0; i<_contacts.length; i++){
     print(contacts[i].phones.first.value);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to access contacts in flutter.

1. [Using contact_service plugin](https://medium.com/xenon-labs/how-to-access-contacts-in-your-flutter-app-3f0158ce1ee7)
2. [Using mobile_number 1.0.4 plugin](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/mobile_number)

**Note: mobile_number plugin works for Android only because getting mobile number of sim card is not supported in iOS.**

Comment: As you can see in the phone's screenshot, I'm getting the phone number there in a list but I need the number to use it in different place, so can you please explain more to me how to solve that using contact_service plugin

Comment: Share sample code of your project, I will check it from my side

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_getContacts() async {
    Future<List<Contact>> futureContacts = ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)
        .then((value) => value.map((e) => Contact.fromMap(e.toMap())).toList());
    var contacts = await futureContacts.then((value) => value.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList());
    print(contacts);
  }
```

Comment: Using this code removes the content (name and phone number in the list) in phone.